# Python thread pool does not work properly on Windows. One thread dominates when running on Windows.

Tags: python, windows, multithreading, threadpool

I have a multi threaded python application, for thread pooling I used code from [here](http://chrisarndt.de/projects/threadpool/). The program engages in network reading excessively and each thread sleep timely to reduce overhead on server it bound.

My development platform is Ubuntu, but the application is for a client who use Windows.

The problem is one thread dominates for long time when it is running on Windows platform, but it is working properly on Ubuntu.

Are there any specific reason on Windows platform related with python threads? or Can somebody suggest a better thread pooling library that I can try?

Thank you.

Comment: I not familiar with the threadpool library, but I have used threads (Using ``thread``) on Windows and haven't experienced any problems.

Comment: I have seen the `threading` library and it seems very easy to use.